# Google apps script "ExecutionResponse" object does not contain "result"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

I am calling a script using the [Google Scripts REST API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run?hl=en). The documentation says that "If the script function returns successfully, [the response] field will contain an ExecutionResponse object with the function's return value as the object's result field."

However, when the response comes back it does not appear to contain a result field. I just get this:

```
{
  "name": "CleanCSV",
  "done": true,
  "response": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse"
  }
}
```

Here's the code that's invoking the API call:

```
function callScript(SCRIPT_ID, SHEET_ID, token) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/' + SCRIPT_ID + ':run', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            console.log(xhr.response); //this is what I pasted above
        };
        xhr.onerror = function() {
            console.log("D'Oh! That didn't work. Please try again");
        };
        var body = {};
        body.function = 'CleanCSV';
        body.parameters = [SHEET_ID];
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
};
```

The Google Script file is pretty simple.

```
function CleanCSV(sid) {

    //identify the sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sid);
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

   //...
   //do some stuff to the sheet
   //...

   return "hi there"; 
   //in reality, this will return some data
}
```

Comment: are you sure you published the latest code?

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. I had hit "update" in the publish dialog, but it seems I needed to publish the script as a new version. If you want to write this as an answer rather than a comment, I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you have not saved a new version of your code or not published the script using that latest version.

see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app